# Magento 1.9 : How to fetch image from url?

Tags: magento-1.9, image-upload

I am using core php functions file_get_contents, file_put_contents but I was asked to change it with alternate functions in magento. I am attaching the following code.

```
$imgUrl         = $picture_url;                            
$newfilename    = 'sample' . rand(0000,9999) . '.png';        
$fullpath       = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . 'import' . DS .$newfilename;                                                  
$image_data     = file_get_contents($imgUrl);                   
$result         = file_put_contents($fullpath,file_get_contents($imgUrl));           
$imgName        = $fullpath;
```

Then **$imgName** passed in addImageToMediaGallery.

Comment: $image_data     = file_get_contents($imgUrl);                   
$result         = file_put_contents($fullpath,$image_data);